# Assigning a php associative array to JS?

Tags: extension, php, javascript

I am trying to assign a php array to js.

// On the Server:

```
CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addVars('myNamespace', array('foo' => 'bar'));
```

// In the JS file or inline script

```
CRM.alert(CRM.vars.myNamespace.foo); // Alerts "bar"
```

It shows me a following error

> TypeError: CRM.vars.myNamespace is undefined

Comment: I dont know the answer, but I would try to see what would happen if you json_encode the assigned array.
Or another debugging is rather than do a alter. You could do a console.log(CRM.vars) and then you can see what is available in the CRM.vars object when you open the developer screen of your browser (in firefox press f12).

Comment: What server file and what js file are you putting these in? They have to both execute on the same page request.